# Bash: How do I stop bash from mindlessly writing millions of lines to console once it has begun?

Tags: bash, console, grep

I do this way too often it is kind of embarrassing.  Regardless, possibly we can put an end to this once and for all?  I just grepped a log file for a mysterious ip that apparently is on every line (it turns out it is the ip for the server itself!  mystery solved).  It turns out this file has millions of lines.  Actually I just checked and it is still going.

Any way to stop this madness?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `^C`? I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: I tried ^C!  Nothing will stop it.

Comment: As others have pointed out, if you have changed `stty` settings, then all bets are off. The normal cause of `Ctrl-C` not responding is that millions of lines streaming out make it very hard for the `Ctrl-C` to 'swim' upstream (through several layers of software) to send it's message. When (on the rare occasion) I have got into this situation, `Ctrl-C` 4-5 times, very rapidly together seems to get through within a few seconds. It could be that even 1 Ctrl-C eventually gets thru, but I'm not patient enough to wait. And finally, as pointed out, you always have `kill -INT, ....` as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, use CTRL+C to interrupt. If for some reason this isn't working for you, open another terminal or console session on the same box and issue this command:

```
ps -o pid=,args= -C grep
```

This will list the Process ID (PID) if each currently running `grep` command. Find the one which corresponds to the one you want to kill and then execute the following commands in sequence, checking after each whether the process has terminated.

```
kill -INT $PID
kill -TERM $PID
kill -QUIT $PID
kill -SEGV $PID
kill -KILL $PID
```

Where `$PID` is the Process ID you identified above.

Note that `-C` is a GNU `ps` extension and may not be supported by other `ps` implementations. If that's the case for you then something like the following might be required:

```
ps -o pid= -o comm= -o args= | awk '$2~/grep/{print $1, $3}'
```

Which is essentially the same.

Comment: Awesome thank you.  For some reason my terminal was not transmitting the signal with ^C.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you pipe the result to more.. this way the results are paged & you can quit by pressing CTRL+C.

your command would be `cat someFile.log | grep someIP | more`

Comment: @Jefromi: `less` is `more`, but more. `most` is more than `less`.

Answer (score 1):

Just hit ctrl-c (with keyboard focus in the terminal in question) to kill the process. Closing the terminal tends to work too, but isn't so clean.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should do the trick. It sends [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29) to the process.

Comment: Only if you haven't stuffed around with `stty` :-)